# What does complex integration over a real interval have to do with center of mass and centroids?

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, complex-integration

I was watching this 3Blue1Brown video about Fourier series https://youtu.be/r6sGWTCMz2k (timestamp: 16:30) and the presenter mentioned that to get the average position of a curve in the complex plane (which he describes as a sort of center of mass) you need to integrate the complex function that "draw" the curve with respect to "time" (a parameter). I don't understand why that makes sense. Could someone help me see the connection?

EDIT: The thing that i do not understand is why should this integral: $$\int_0^1 f(t) \, dt$$
(Where $f(t)$ is a complex function that, as $t$ ranges from $0$ to $1$, describes a curve in the complex plane) Represents the avarage position of points / "center" / "center of mass" of the drawing.

I understand why this average position can be a kind of center of mass and I understand why the curve is described by this $t$ parameter. What confuses me is just the fact that the integral shown above precisely gives the complex number associated with the center of mass of the curve.

[image: Image from the 3b1b video]
Image from the 3b1b video (modified)

Comment: What doesn't make sense? Calling a parameter "time"? Using a parameter to describe a curve? Using integration to find a center of mass? Identifying center of mass as an average position of points in a figure? There's a lot to unpack here, and if we have no idea what you **do** understand, it's hard to see how to help with the parts you don't understand.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I tried to improve the question and make it clear what I do and what I don't understand.

Comment: Do you understand the 1-dimensional case, if $f(t)$ was real-valued instead of complex-valued?

Comment: I think so. It would represent the average value of the function between 0 and 1. But it's not clear to me why this generalizes to an arbitrary curve in the complex plane.

Comment: So if you were plotting a curve in Cartesian coordinates using $x = g(t)$ and $y = h(t)$, for $0 \leq t \leq 1,$ the integral of $g(t)$ would be the average $x$ coordinate and the integral of $h(t)$ would be the average $y$ coordinate. This is kind of like that, except that instead of $g(t)$ we have the real part of $f(t)$ and instead of $h(t)$ we have the imaginary part of $f(t).$

Comment: By the way, the "center of mass" thing could be misleading, because the average is weighted by the amount of *time* spent in each part of the curve, not by the path length of each part of the curve. So it's really not a center of mass of the curve in the way we usually would consider the center of mass of a curve.

Comment: @DavidK Agreed. You should have an arclength parametrization $f(t)$ for the physical interpretation to be valid.

Comment: @DavidK Thank you. I get it now :)

Comment: I think one way to visualize that would be to introduce another axis for the t parameter. Than it would become just a regular integral of $g(t)$ in the $x-t$ plane and another regular integral of $h(t)$ in the $y-t$ plane. Thanks again for the insight.